# View Gravity not working

Tags: android

Im overlaying a linearlayout.The layout contains a button.The button should be top right of the linearlayout.But gravity doesnt seem to work.

CODE:
Inside the onCreate method of my service.

```
   final WindowManager.LayoutParams params3 = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
           WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL  |   WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH |              WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

   LinearLayout ll=new LinearLayout(this);
   LinearLayout ll2=new LinearLayout(this);
   LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
   lp.gravity=Gravity.RIGHT;
   lp.width=30;
   lp.height=30;

   b=new Button(this);
   b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.x);
   params3.gravity=Gravity.TOP;
   params3.height=200;
   params3.width=200;

   ll.addView(b, lp);
   wm.addView(ll, params3);
```

The linearlayout 200X200 is created and is on top.But the button isnt top right.I tried using
b.setWidth and b.setHeight. would not help.

Comment: lp.gravity=Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT

Answer (score 2):

LinearLayout by default is horizontal
You can't align horizontally in horizontal LinearLayout (e.g right, center_horizontal, left) and you can't align vertically in vertical LinearLayout (e.g top center_vertical, bottom) in vertical LinearLayout.

If you need to align it to the right you must either set your LinearLayout to be vertical or use a different ViewGroup, for example FrameLayout.

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.setOrientation(LinarLayout.VERTICAL);
```

Ant the Buttom will always be on top since it's a first item.
And why not doing it in xml? It will be much easier when less code.

Edit:
To put button to top right of the VideoView your layout will look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/videoView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/videoView1"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Put this layout in a layout res folder of the project.
Project/res/layout/your_layout.xml

To attach a layout to Activity's window:

```
public final class YourActivity
        extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);

        // Get VideoView
        VideoView vv = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

        //get Button reference
        View button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
    }
}
```

Comment: thankyou :)
and now if i want to add a video view to my layout. video size 200x200. with the button staying top right of the video??

Comment: Sorry, forgot. Update again. You don't need to do anything with the WindowManager. You should do more reading about Activities, Fragments and layouts. Read some android getting started book.